# how to detect loaded data of html using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, preloader

The concept that I have is about to create a preloader html for my website.
In flash when I needed to detect loaded data and compare it with total data in order to create a loading bar I was using following AS3 code:

```
var total:Number = this.stage.loaderInfo.bytesTotal;
var loaded:Number = this.stage.loaderInfo.bytesLoaded;
```

now I'm looking for similar thing in js. but this time I need to found the size of all of my external assets and compare it with loaded amount and wait for it to load, then when it's done , I'm gonna show my html page.

I have read sth about jQuery.load() but sound's to me like it's just load a single html file without taking care about the external assets.

Comment: you could write a loader javascript which loads other scripts, images and style sheets. Each of these have a "load" event in which you can have a callback.

Comment: I know that. But the question is how should I write the loader javascript.

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel: http://thinkpixellab.com/pxloader/

Comment: Reinventing the wheel is a good idea all the time, Because it makes you understand how exactly the machine works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Udacity](https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-cs255/l-52850042/e-52862121/m-112453311):

```
var gCachedAssets = {};

function loadAssets(assetList, callbackFcn) {
    // All the information we need to keep track of
    // for this batch.
    var loadBatch = {
        count: 0,
        total: assetList.length,
        cb: callbackFcn
    };

    for(var i = 0; i < assetList.length; i++) {
        if(gCachedAssets[assetList[i]] === null) {
            var assetType = getAssetTypeFromExtension(assetList[i]);

            if(assetType === 0) { // Asset is an image
                var img = new Image();
                img.onload = function () {
                    onLoadedCallback(img, loadBatch);
                };
                img.src = assetList[i];
                gCachedAssets[assetList[i]] = img;

            } else if(assetType === 1) { // Asset is Javascript
                var fileref = document.createElement('script');
                fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
                fileref.onload = function (e){
                    onLoadedCallback(fileref,loadBatch);
                };
                fileref.setAttribute("src", filename);
                document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
                gCachedAssets[assetList[i]] = fileref;
            }

        } else { // Asset is already loaded
            onLoadedCallback(gCachedAssets[assetList[i]], loadBatch);
        }
    }
}

function onLoadedCallback(asset, batch) {
    // If the entire batch has been loaded,
    // call the callback.
    batch.count++;
    if(batch.count == batch.total) {
        batch.cb(asset);
    }
}

function getAssetTypeFromExtension(fname) {
    if(fname.indexOf('.jpg') != -1 || fname.indexOf('.jpeg') != -1 || fname.indexOf('.png') != -1 || fname.indexOf('.gif') != -1 || fname.indexOf('.wp') != -1) {
        // It's an image!
        return 0;
    }

    if(fname.indexOf('.js') != -1 || fname.indexOf('.json') != -1) {
        // It's javascript!
        return 1;
    }

    // Uh Oh
    return -1;
}
```

To use it, provide the assets' file names as an array of strings to `loadAssets`. The `callbackFcn` triggers when all assets are loaded, while `onLoadedCallback` gets called every time an individual asset is loaded.

Since, for security restrictions for Javascript, you cannot get the number of bytes to load v/s number of bytes loaded, you can use instead the number of assets loaded v/s the number of assets to load given by the `batch` object (`batch.count / batch.total`).

Comment: I used you code on my website. It's working offline as it's expected but not online! you'll make me happy if you check my website and find out the bug. it's topdesignstudio.ir - I used your code in loader.js